# Wordpress template list not showing up in posts

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm facing a very common problem with Wordpress, I don't see the list of my templates in the post edit page. There are tons of posts about this here but I haven't found the solution to my problem in any of them.

I basically have this in my theme directory: index.php, page.php, header.php, functions.php, sidebar.php, style.css

in page.php and index.php, I have:

```
/*
Template Name: HOME
*/
```

and

```
/*
Template Name: PAGE
*/
```

What I've already tried:
 - switched back to the original Wordpress theme and back to mine
 - made sure permission 755 was attributed to folder
 - copied a working file from another theme and inserted my code into it
 - completely logged out and came back

but nothing worked, I still don't see the list of templates for my theme while for official themes, I do see the list of page templates.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *index.php* or *page.php* as a Page Template, because those files are reserved for other templates of a theme.

As the [Page Template reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) states:

> Name your template file so you can easily identify its Template Name, e.g., filename **my-custom-page.php** for template name "My Custom Page". Some coders group their templates with a filename prefix, such as page_my-custom-page.php (Don't use page- prefix as WordPress will interpret the file as a specialized page template.)
>
> For information on Theme file-naming conventions and filenames you **cannot** use, see [reserved Theme filenames](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List).

Comment: Hello D79, thanks. Unfortunately I forgot to say I had also tried that. I now have content-home.php and content-page.php with the appropriate comments inside but nothing is showing up when writing a new post.

Comment: Are you sure the theme is active? It should have at least a style.css ([well formed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet)), an index.php and a function.php file to work.

Comment: yes theme is active and working (site is displayed correctly). I did a copy/paste of the stylesheet format. I have a index.php and functions.php and they are also working fine.

Comment: and you're writing a new page, not post, right? (this works only with pages). if so then only checking the entire theme could allow me to understand what's wrong, so if you want please provide the zip archive.

Comment: That's strange because when I use twentyfifteen for example, I can select multiple templates for posts. For my theme, I can indeed see the templates from my theme. Is there no way to have the same for posts?

Comment: Maybe you're talking about [Post Formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)? Please see also the [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for more infos about the template options available.